# Создание нового датасета с помощью GroupBy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Есть датасет `reviews1`, в котором есть столбцы `points` и `taster_name`.
Я хочу построить зависимость между количеством оценок совершенных экспертом и среднем отклонением его оценок от средней оценки.

Фактически, меня бы устроило следующее выражение:

```py
reviews1.plot.hexbin(x='reviews1.groupby('taster_name').points.std()', y='reviews1.groupby('taster_name').points.count()', gridsize=10)
```

Или хотя бы заработавшее такое:

```py
reviews1.plot.hexbin(x='reviews1.groupby('taster_name').points.std()', y='reviews1.groupby('taster_name').points.mean()-reviews1.points.mean()', gridsize=10)
```

Однако это выдает ошибку:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Пробовал создавать новый датасет, но при создании нового, при присвоении операции `GroupBy()` выдает либо ошибку, либо делает все числа `NaN`.

Как вообще проще всего строить зависимости по таким сложно сгруппированным данным с помощью Pandas? Понимаю, что возможность должна быть, но во всех обучающих примеры только простых зависимостей.

Датасет:
[image: а]

Comment: а зачем вы x=... берете в кавычки?

Comment: Честно говоря, посмотрел аналог в туториале. На питоне новичок, а без ковычек выдавало  "None of [Float64Index([1.9345106992266188, 2.5613594472711303, 7],\n             dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Приведите пример исходного датасета

Comment: country - Italy points - 87      taster_name  - Kerin O’Keefe

Comment: Понял в чем дело по первому - правильнее без кавычек, но график оно построить не может, так как ни те, ни те значения не являются возможными для оси. Добавил картинку датасета

Comment: Нет, картинкой не пойдет. Нужно в текстовом виде. Надо же попытаться воспроизвести вашу задачу, а не "лечить по фотографии".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davestroud/Wine/master/winemag-data-130k-v2.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
res = df.groupby("taster_name")["points"].agg(["std","count"])
```

---

Результат:

```
In [15]: res
Out[15]:
                         std  count
taster_name
Alexander Peartree  1.934511    415
Anna Lee C. Iijima  2.561359   4415
Anne Krebiehl MW    2.373100   3685
Carrie Dykes        1.998618    139
Christina Pickard   3.600926      6
Fiona Adams         1.739437     27
Jeff Jenssen        2.022727    491
Jim Gordon          2.698341   4177
Joe Czerwinski      2.858701   5147
Kerin O’Keefe       2.474240  10776
Lauren Buzzeo       2.530672   1835
Matt Kettmann       2.571257   6332
Michael Schachner   3.022859  15134
Mike DeSimone       1.992549    514
Paul Gregutt        2.814445   9532
Roger Voss          3.036373  25514
Sean P. Sullivan    2.458547   4966
Susan Kostrzewa     2.376140   1085
Virginie Boone      2.996796   9537

In [16]: res.plot.hexbin(x="std", y="count", gridsize=10)
Out[16]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x134dc7d80b8>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]